# How do I make weight painting not a living torment?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

So I got a pretty high res mesh that I've managed to get down to around 600k verts. But I still have extreme low performance in weight paint mode in the viewport which makes it so much harder to work. I get like a 3 second delay after each stroke and it doesn't help that this is my first time rigging a character and I have barely any idea if I'm doing it correctly. Any tips or is this just the sad reality?

EDIT: here's a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: 600k is just too much. You will have to do a (manual) retopology preserving the high details only through maps. Giving us a screenshot of your model could also help.

Comment: @Leander i used instant meshes for quick retopo and  then a multires with shrinkwrap to preserve the details for later. how exactly would i go on with the way you said?

Comment: Your mesh (before the multires) has to many vertices, try getting to 10k-40k. There are plenty of tutorials on how to do a retopo on a highres model.

Comment: @Leander manual retopo seemed too tedious to me and i wanted to do a shortcut. i'll try it in the future, but so far, i think i can manage. at least i can rest easy knowing that there's an easier way, thanks

Comment: "manual retopo seemed too tedious" and "knowing that there's an easier way" doesn't seem to match. Yes, topology is hard, but there's a reason for it. Good Luck!

Comment: if you plan to animate a very high poly mesh it's going to be horrible... as Leander said you should retopologize your object, then bake the high-poly to keep all the 3D details on the low-poly with a normal map, it will be a huge relief

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retopologize your mesh. Once you´re done, then you can assign weights using armature.
Also: Select your mesh, use the modifier: DECIMATE: Choose 50%. Check if your model is ok for you in shape. If it is and you´ve reduced the polycount to half, please reconsider retopologize. Basically you can´t work with an armature on a very dense mesh.

Thank you for your consideration to vote me as the answer by clicking to the left :the icon with a check mark and upvote this answer.

BFCT_Schiller